# Generate QR code in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have written a code to scan a QR code. But, I want to generate a QR code by taking input from text box or any other source. I have been looking for it but there seems to be not such option. I have to write native code and I'm having problem doing that. Please guide me.
I have done this -

```
    final TextField text = new TextField();
    final SpanButton qrGen = new SpanButton("Generate QR");
    qrGen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Comes here.....");
            MyNative n = (MyNative)NativeLookup.create(MyNative.class) ;
            if(n != null && n.isSupported()) {
                String path = (String) evt.getSource();
                System.out.println("Comes here2.....");
                InputStream is = null;
                try {
                    is = com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(path);
                    System.out.println("Comes here3.....");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Image i = null;
                try {
                    i = Image.createImage(is);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//(n.genQR(text.getText()));
                ImageViewer iv = new ImageViewer(i);
                g.removeAll();
                g.addComponent(iv);
                f.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, g);
                f.show();
            }
        }
    });
    g.addComponent(text);
    g.addComponent(qrGen);
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, g);
    f.show();
```

The `MyNative` object stays null and the inner block is never reached.
This is my native implementation -

```
package com.codename1;

import com.google.zxing.QRCodeWriter;

public class MyNativeImpl implements MyNative {
public Object genQR(String param) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
    try {
        return encodeAsBitmap(STR);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = new QRCodeWriter().encode(str, 
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, WIDTH, WIDTH, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int w = result.getWidth();
    int h = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        int offset = y * w;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, w, h);
    return bitmap;
}

public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The native interface will only work on the device itself.

It doesn't look like your native interface is valid since you return an Object from the interface which is illegal. You should return a `byte[]`.

Native arguments/return types are limited for better language interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is going to be running online, I will suggest you use [Google QR code api](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes). It generates a QR for you, return an image and doesn't require writing native code. Sample of Google QR image [here](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world&choe=UTF-8&chs=500x500). Otherwise you should debug your app using real device, as native interface won't work on simulator unless you write a java native code too.

Code below should help you with your native interface, not tested and written here on stackoverflow:

**Android MyNativeImpl.java:**

```
package com.yourpackage.anything;

import com.google.zxing.QRCodeWriter;

public class MyNativeImpl {
public byte[] generateQRFromString(String str) throws WriterException {
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = new QRCodeWriter().encode(str,
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, WIDTH, WIDTH, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int w = result.getWidth();
    int h = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        int offset = y * w;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, w, h);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
}
```

**MyNative.java**

```
package com.yourpackage.anything;

import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;
public interface MyNative extends NativeInterface {
    public byte[] generateQRFromString(String str);
}
```

Now you can convert the byte[] returned to image in your CN1 code. If you don't know how, Check out CN1 Javadoc or @Shai might be able to help you with a snippet. Based on what you're trying to do, you can try below:

```
    final TextField text = new TextField();
    final SpanButton qrGen = new SpanButton("Generate QR");
    qrGen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("Comes here.....");
            MyNative n = (MyNative) NativeLookup.create(MyNative.class);
            if (n != null && n.isSupported()) {
                byte[] byteData = n.generateQRFromString("Hello world");
                if (byteData != null) {
                    Image img = Image.createImage(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
                    ImageViewer iv = new ImageViewer(img);
                    g.removeAll();
                    g.addComponent(iv);
                    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, g);
                    f.show();
                } else {
                    //print My native code returned no image
                }

            }
        }
    });
    g.addComponent(text);
    g.addComponent(qrGen);
    f.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, g);
    f.show();
```